# DB STARTUP command active for an online database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recovery

We had a maintenance activity done on our SQL Servers and after that, we restarted the services. Now the databases took their sweet time to recover and after recovery, we started some jobs thinking that everything is good. Now one of the job runs was blocked by a spid that has its command as DB STARTUP. Suspiciously, I checked the SQL Server logs and there it was showing that one database was still recovering. However, in the object explorer I am able to see that database as online and also I can query the database. I even did some fake updates and truncated some tables too in that database. So, what recovery is exactly going on here? The databases are in AOAG, if that helps.

Comment: What is output of `select @@version`, if you have enterprise edition then you have fast recovery in which database can come online after second phase of recovery and in background third phase can continue. I will add the answer after your revert

Comment: It is an enterprise version. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU1) (KB3123299) - 11.0.6518.0 (X64)

Answer (score 2):

As confirmed by you the SQL server is of enterprise version and database was not starting after restore so the recovery process can utilize [fast recovery](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/lock-logging-and-fast-recovery/).  In enterprise edition the database would come online after second phase (this is called Fast recovery which was introduced from SS 2005 onwards) and you would see database as online but still internally third phase, the UNDO, phase is going on and would be accessible completely only after third phase completes. What I mean by completely is For fast recovery, a query may bump into one of the locks being held to allow fast recovery – in which case it will have to wait for that lock to be dropped as UNDO progresses

I suggest you also read

- [When is fast recovery used](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/fast-recovery-used/)
- [3 phases of recovery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: But the DB STARTUP is blocking only one particular spid. Other operations are unaffected. So this means that the lock is there on the objects that the job is trying to alter?

Comment: Can you tell me what is the operation doing which is being blocked by DB startup ?

Comment: It is a step in a job which truncates some tables.  Weird thing is , the DB Startup blocks the job step but it allowed me to truncate those tables manually.

Comment: Can you post the errorlog in the question ?, I need to see information whether database has recovered or not. You can also upload erorrlog on  shared drive and share link in the question.

Comment: @karun10 Are you going to share the output ?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone finds this, each database in an availability group has a redo thread, and the command is always `DB STARTUP`. In fact, that is how you can identify the redo spid associated with each database - `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests WHERE command = 'DB STARTUP'`.

Additional troubleshooting information is available in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/troubleshoot-availability-group-exceeded-rto?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score -2):

It seems the database is not recovered completely. Please check the SQL server log. Lock will release automatically once database completely recovered.